# Remove Categories from Layered Navigation - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, layered-navigation

I would like to remove the categories section on the layered navigation but do not see where they are called within layered navigation module.

Comment: Are you using multiple languages?

Comment: No, just english. It is the sub-categories that are displayed in Layered Navigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the following file:

> /vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_LayeredNavigation/templates/layer/view.phtml

to your theme:

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_LayeredNavigation/templates/layer/view.phtml

And put the **Category** condition like below:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php
/**
 * Category layered navigation
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation
 */
?>

<?php if ($block->canShowBlock()): ?>
    <div class="block filter">
        <div class="block-title filter-title">
            <strong><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Shop By') ?></strong>
        </div>

        <div class="block-content filter-content">
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('state') ?>

            <?php if ($block->getLayer()->getState()->getFilters()): ?>
                <div class="block-actions filter-actions">
                    <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getClearUrl() ?>" class="action clear filter-clear"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Clear All') ?></span></a>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php $wrapOptions = false; ?>
            <?php foreach ($block->getFilters() as $filter): ?>
                <?php if (!$wrapOptions): ?>
                    <strong role="heading" aria-level="2" class="block-subtitle filter-subtitle"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Shopping Options') ?></strong>
                    <dl class="filter-options" id="narrow-by-list">
                <?php $wrapOptions = true; endif; ?>
                    <?php if ($filter->getItemsCount() && $filter->getName() != 'Category'): ?>
                        <dt role="heading" aria-level="3" class="filter-options-title"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__($filter->getName())) ?></dt>
                        <dd class="filter-options-content"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getChildBlock('renderer')->render($filter) ?></dd>
                    <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php if ($wrapOptions): ?>
                </dl>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Use the above content for your view.phtml file.

Comment: This worked to remove the categories but broke the mobile. The 'Shop By' button becomes unclickable. When I revert the changes, the button then works.

Comment: Are you working with luma theme or parent theme is luma theme?

Comment: I built custom theme based on Luma.

Comment: I have updated my answer. You need to copy the view.phtml from vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_LayeredNavigation/templates/layer/view.phtml

Answer (score 6):

Checked with M2.4.1. There is a configuration here Store -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The layered navigation categories are called in one of the core files as below:

```
/vendor/magento/module-layered-navigation/view/frontend/templates/layer/view.phtml
```

You need to override this file in your theme and then change the content of the file however you want.

Add below directory in your theme:

```
app/design/frontend/vendor_name/theme_name/Magento_LayeredNavigation/templates/layer
```

Then put above file `view.phtml` in this path.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2.3.4:

1. copy file **vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_LayeredNavigation/templates/layer/view.phtml** to **/Magento_LayeredNavigation/templates/layer/view.phtml**
2. Find `<?php if ($filter->getItemsCount()) : ?>`
3. Replace with `<?php if ($filter->getItemsCount() && get_class($filter) != \Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Category::class) : ?>`